# Vim: How do I search for a word which is not followed by another word?

Tags: regex, vim

Pretty basic question, I'm trying to write a regex in Vim to match any phrase starting with `"abc "` directly followed by anything other than `"defg"`.

I've used `"[^defg]"` to match any single character other than d, e, f or g.

My first instinct was to try `/abc [^\(defg\)]` or `/abc [^\<defg\>]` but neither one of those works.

Comment: do you mean preceeded? or followed by?  Your examples seem to imply followed by.

Comment: Suggestion to change the title of this question to "Vim: How do I search for a word which is not followed by another word?". Reason: We are not excluding an entire word from the search as the title suggests.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Here's the search string.

```
/abc \(defg\)\@!
```

The concept you're looking for is called a negative look-ahead assertion.  Try this in vim for more info:

```
:help \@!
```

Answer (score 21):

preceeded or followed by?

If it's anything starting with 'abc ' that's not (immediately) followed by 'defg', you want [bmdhacks' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96826/vim-how-do-i-exclude-an-entire-word-from-my-search#97008).

If it's anything starting with 'abc ' that's not (immediately) preceeded by 'defg', you want a negative lookbehind:

```
/\%(defg\)\@<!abc /
```

This will match any occurance of 'abc ' as long as it's not part of 'defgabc '. See `:help \@<!` for more details.

If you want to match 'abc ' as long as it's not part of 'defg.*abc ', then just add a `.*`:

```
/\%(defg.*\)\@<!abc /
```

Matching 'abc ' only on lines where 'defg' doesn't occur is similar:

```
/\%(defg.*\)\@<!abc \%(.*defg\)\@!/
```

Although, if you're just doing this for a substitution, you can make this easier by combining `:v//` and `:s//`

```
:%v/defg/s/abc /<whatever>/g
```

This will substitute '<whatever>' for 'abc ' on all lines that don't contain 'defg'.  See `:help :v` for more.

Comment: That works but it's so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, this is a hairy one:

```
/\%(\%(.\{-}\)\@<=XXXXXX\zs\)*
```

(replace XXXXXX with the search word). This will search for everything that does *not* contain XXXXXX. I imagine if you did:

```
/abc \%(\%(.\{-}\)\@<=defg\zs\)*
```

This may work like you want it to. Hope this helps a little!

Comment: This is unbelievable complex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment Andy's answer, but his answer is wrong, so I explain it here,  the expression"/abc\ [^d][^e][^f][^g]" is not match 'abc d111', 'abc def1' etc.
the best way is the expression "/abc (defg)@!"

Comment: i.e the "negated set" check for individual characters, while the "negative lookahead" take the whole word into account.

Answer (score -4):

/abc\ [^d][^e][^f][^g]

It's pretty cumbersome for larger words, but works like a charm.

Comment: Won't that also not match "abc daaa"?